# how to pass a List as a parameter to a method in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is the function I am returning the list from. The list has values when its sent from this method.

```
  public ActionResult searchItemReview(string searchItem, int userId)
    {

        if (userId > 0) {
            saveReviewHistory(searchItem, userId);
        }

        string cxCnet = "004414622588908206393:to_4_i9qoqs";
        string cxTrustedReviews = "004414622588908206393:mfbtsoruifs";

        allReviewList revList = new allReviewList();

        RootObject urlLinks = googleSearch.getSearchResults(searchItem, cxCnet);
        reviewCnet searchItemRevCnet = scrapData.scrapSitesCnet(urlLinks);
        RootObject urlLink = googleSearch.getSearchResults(searchItem, cxTrustedReviews);
        reviewCnet searchItemRev = scrapData.scrapSiteMobileTrustedreviews(urlLink);

        searchItemRevCnet.trustedReview = searchItemRev.trustedReview;

        revList.reviewList.Add(searchItemRevCnet);

        return RedirectToAction("searchReview", "home", revList);
    }
```

This is the Action Result which is called from the method above.

```
public ActionResult searchReview(allReviewList searchItemRev)
    {

        if (searchItemRev.reviewList.Count != 0)
        {
            searchItemRev.reviewList[0].hasReview = "hasReview";
        }
        return View(searchItemRev);
    }
```

This is my model:

```
  public class reviewCnet
{
    public string goodReview { get; set; }
    public string badReview { get; set; }
    public string conclusion { get; set; }
    public string hasReview { get; set; }
    public string trustedReview {get;set;}

    //public List<user> userList = new List<user>();

}

public class allReviewList
{
    public List<reviewCnet> reviewList { get; set; }

    public allReviewList()
    {
        reviewList = new List<reviewCnet>();
    }
}
```

I cant figure out whats wrong with this. If I don't have the constructor in the model I get an error saying object reference is not an instance of an object....

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot pass a complex object containing properties which are complex objects or collection using `RedirectToAction()` (internally the method calls `.ToString()` on each property of `allReviewList` so the result is "System.Collections.Generic.List[reviewCnet]"`)

Comment: But what is the point of this. Just pass `searchItem` and `userId` to `searchReview()` and generate the data in that method.

Comment: this makes the code luk a bit messy bt this works thank u :) @StephenMuecke

Comment: Its just moving the code from one method to another (and deleting the `searchItemReview()` method) so not sure what you mean by _messy_

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an object like that in a URL redirect.  One thing that might be worth trying is storing the list in TempData like so:

```
TempData["revList"] = revList;
return RedirectToAction("searchReview", "home");
```

Then in your searchReview Action in the home Controller:

```
var revList= TempData["revList"] as allReviewList;
```

Comment: so how do I access the values stored inside revList in my view ?

Comment: In this approach you remove the input from controller and read `TempData["revList"]` inside it.

Comment: Get rid of your allReviewsList class. In your first action method use: allReviewList revList = new List<reviewCnet>...

Comment: `TempData` lasts one request. If the user refreshes the browser, the data is all lost.

Comment: I am confused as to what you mean by in your view?  If you can get the list out of TempData in the Action method that you are redirecting to, then create a ViewModel that you add your list to and pass to your view.

If revList inside "searchReview" action is null, it is probably because it is being cast as List<reviewCnet> when it is actually an "allReviewList" object...  see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can parse your data into an string maybe using JSon or XML and deserialize it where you want to use it. It will be a better approach if you want to use this data in client side using Javascript maybe.

```
public ActionResult searchItemReview(string searchItem, int userId)
{
    .
    .
    .
    var str = Json.Encode(revList);
    return RedirectToAction("searchReview", "home", str);
}
```

Again it's better if you need the data in client side processing otherwise Nick's approach is better.